# Python : Folium map not appearing

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, geojson, folium

I am trying to map some data for Canada using Folium. However, in the end, I am getting whitespace as an output with no error message. My code is below.

```
import folium
import json # or import geojson

with open("geo.json") as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file) # geojson file

# create a plain world map
can_map = folium.Map(location=[56.1, 106], zoom_start=2, tiles='Mapbox     
Bright')

c2 = {
  'Alberta': 144284.48,
  'British Columbia': 141222.06000000017,
  'Manitoba': 134337.96999999994,
  'New Brunswick': 115727.67000000001,
  'Newfoundland': 6885.140000000001,
  'Northwest Territories': 91755.44000000002,
  'Nova Scotia': 80136.18000000005,
  'Nunavut': 1506.4300000000014,
  'Ontario': 352263.50999999983,
  'Prince Edward Island': 28742.2,
  'Quebec': 138658.87999999998,
  'Saskachewan': 177314.26000000013,
  'Yukon': 74404.80000000003
}

# generate choropleth map using the total immigration of each country to Canada from 1980 to 2013
can_map.choropleth(
  geo_data=json_data,
  data=c2,
  columns=['Province', 'Profit'],
  key_on='feature.properties.name',
  fill_color='YlOrRd', 
  fill_opacity=0.7, 
  line_opacity=0.2,
  legend_name='Canada data'
)

# display map
can_map
```

The json file I am using can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codeforamerica/click_that_hood/master/public/data/canada.geojson)

Comment: As you already discovered, you cannot plot interactive maps from a python script ran on command line. If you don't want to use **Jupyter**, the only way would be to first create an HTML file of the plot, that contains all the needed JS for rendering the map functionality, and open it in your browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works for me in a Jupyter notebook as is:

[image]

For a script, you need to call the `save` method, like so:

```py
can_map.save('index.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-run the code in Firefox and it should render in Jupyter notebook.
When you save the map in another browser that saved file should open properly even if it appears as a white cell initially.